# Change css chips on validation error

Tags: css, validation, primefaces

I am working with primefaces and using the element "chips" to introduce multiple e-mails, i validate the format of them and im trying to change the style of the "bubbles" to ui-state-error if the validation is wrong

My chips:

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-1" style="margin-right: 5px;">
        <p:chips id="chips" required="true" value="#{Contactos.lista_email}"
                placeholder="Email" style="color: red;"
                requiredMessage="ERROR: El campo 'Email' es obligatorio" 
                validator="ValidMail"/>
</div>
```

My validator:

```
@FacesValidator(value = "ValidMail")
public class validatorMail implements Validator{

private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;

private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN =
    "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
    + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) throws ValidatorException {

    ArrayList<String> aux = (ArrayList<String>) value;
    String error = null;

    final String EMAIL_PATTERN =
        "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
        + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    //Check if user has typed only blank spaces
    if(value.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("ERROR: Email requiere un formato válido", "Email: requiere un formato válido");
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        throw new ValidatorException(msg);
    }
    else {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        for (String temp : aux){
            boolean valid = this.validate(temp);
                if (valid == false){
                    if (error == null) error = temp;
                    else error = error + "\n" + temp;
                }
        }

        if (error != null){
            chips.setValid(false);
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("ERROR DE FORMATO: "+"\n" + error, " ");
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            chips.setValid(false);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }   
    }

}
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to set seperate chip-elements invalid. The primefaces component `org.primefaces.component.chips.Chips` doesn't provide means for that in version 6.1. You could of course open a feature request on [github](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues).

The only way for now is to set the whole component invalid and provide an appropriate text inside your `FacesMessage`

`((UIInput) component).setValid(false);`